# Detailed explanation about Python's "freeze"

Tags: python, freeze

Is there anywhere a detailed explanation about Python's "freeze" thing? I saw the PyPi page, but I don't think it's comprehensive enough.

Comment: What "freeze" thing are you referring to?

Comment: Something related to making a script executable.

Answer (score 6):

There is documentation about [freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) on the wiki and the [source docstring](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/freeze/freeze.py) is pretty good.. There is an alternative, [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). For windows there is [py2exe](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe).  For Macs, [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).

Unless you are trying to make a single-download type program for windows, it is often easier to rely on eggs or source packages installed via setup.py/setuptools/distribute/pip.

Comment: Freeze is good when you are not able to guarantee that the destination machine will have python - it then makes perfect sense.